# SD card not detected through Storage Sense

Tags: 8.1, storage, micro-sd

I am running Windows Phone 8.1 (8.10.12397.895) on a Nokia Lumia 810.

Recently, I put an 8 GB microSD card in to the phone only to find the following.

## **Storage Sense**

[image]

## **Files app**

[image]

So the memory card is not visible to Storage Sense but the phone is actively using the memory card.

[I found someone else who seems to have reported the issue here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/434c45aa-6bd3-4c65-b761-3d2e1e1cd05b/windows-phone-81-sd-card-not-found?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/434c45aa-6bd3-4c65-b761-3d2e1e1cd05b/windows-phone-81-sd-card-not-found?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/434c45aa-6bd3-4c65-b761-3d2e1e1cd05b/windows-phone-81-sd-card-not-found?forum=winphoneosissues). However, the up-voted workaround doesn't work for me because my phone doesn't stay switched on without the battery in.

Comment: Have you tried other SD cards? I have heard of issues where certain types of SD cards will not work properly.

Comment: Haven't tried other SD cards but have tried this SD card in other devices and it works. It seems like a Storage Sense problem because my phone is actively using the SD card to back stuff up

Comment: Could be a firmware issue, meaning you might need to wait for the cyan update from your carrier. If you have recently gotten this update then no idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled that factory reset when the card is inserted should help. Using "reset your phone" in settings on Nokia 530 with 16 GB Kingston card solved the issue. This is really last option because it deletes all data on phone.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: I think it was here: http://forums.windowscentral.com/nokia-lumia-635/297493-nokia-635-wont-detect-sd-card.html

Comment: I can confirm that a hard reset does fix this issue.